# From character to posixct

Tags: r, date, posixct

I have this character type vector that consists of a year and a month. I want to convert it to a date type, but when I try to do this with the POSIXct function, I get the error:

```
 Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
   character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I can't seem to figure out why it won't work. Anyone?

```
 old <- as.character("201702")

 library(lubridate)
 new <- as.POSIXct(date, origin = "201501")
```

Comment: please don't post the solution as part of your question. If you think it's useful, you can post the solution as an answer to your own question ... also, you seem to have changed the definition of your question (do you want the results as POSIXct or Date) ?

Comment: Sorry, I removed the solution in my question and already marked the provided solution below as the helpfull one

Comment: fine, although I do think your answer (which used numeric processing rather than string processing to add the day) was an interesting slightly alternative solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to convert to a date first with the appropriate formatting:

```
as.POSIXct(as.Date("201702", format = "%Y%m"))
```

You could also assume the you want the 1st of the month?

```
as.POSIXct(as.Date(paste0("201702", "01"), format = "%Y%m%d"))
```

Be careful with POSIX dates because they contain the time as well and then timezone that you specify can therefore also play a role in the date you get.

Comment: `%M` is for minutes. How can you use it for months?

Comment: I think you can't.  I think you need `as.Date(paste0("201710","01"),format="%Y%m%d")` (doesn't work without appending the day)

Comment: Thanks, I typed a little fast there.

Comment: Thank you all, I have reached a fulfilling solution and will add it to my question

Comment: note that the first solution (without adding the day to the string) gives `NA`